# Example of equicontinuous functions $f_n:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that no partial sequence converges pointwise

Tags: real-analysis

> Give an example of equicontinuous functions $f_n:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that no partial sequence converges pointwise

Here we have at least two requirements from Ascoli-Arzèla theorem which are missing first the domain is not compact and also we don't impose uniformly bounded condition.

Unfortunately I just saw the definition of equicontinuity and the statement of Ascoli-Arzèla so I'm lacking a good intuition to find such a example.

Comment: What about $f_n(x)=x-n$ ?

Comment: @MartinR it may very well work, as I said I saw so little of equicontinuous functions. I'll check your example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The family $f_n(x) = x-n$ is equicontinous, it is even uniformly equicontinuous: For $\varepsilon > 0$ we can choose $\delta  = \varepsilon$, so that
$$
 |x_1 - x_2 | < \varepsilon \implies |f_n(x_1) - f_n(x_2)| = |(x_1-n) - (x_2-n)|
= |x_1 - x_2 | < \varepsilon \, .
$$

But no subsequence $f_{n_k}(x) = x - n_k$ converges at any point $x$.

Comment: A little simpler is $f_n\equiv n$

Comment: @zhw.: That is true ...